# How to change committed by in Git?

Tags: git

I want to change in my last commit "Committer" field (please note that it not the same field as "Author"). When I use git --amend --author, it changed just "Author" field. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean the _committer_ field?

Comment: @1615903, yes, Commiter, not Author.

Comment: Solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-git can be applied, just remove the parts that touch author if you need to.

Comment: @1615903, thanks a lot!